# Texstudio compiles after keyboard input: ^t

Tags: texstudio

When I enter ^t on my keyboard (shift+^+t) in texstudio, then the document is compiled without t being written in the editor, leaving the ^ without an argument, resulting in an error. I can work around this by entering (shift+^+space+t) instead. However, other letters do not give me this trouble (e.g. shift+^+s is results in ^s being written to the editor). What is going on?

Comment: This doesn't seem like default behaviour. Do you have any macros set in TXS? Also, please mention what TXS version you are on, what OS and your keyboard layout may also be relevant. Does this also happen if you use default settings ? (with TXS closed, delete / make a backup copy of `.config/texstudio.ini` and restart TXS.)

Comment: No macros. TeXstudio 2.12.4 (hg 6476:3e5c3afa4719) Using Qt Version 5.6.2, compiled with Qt 5.6.2 R. Windows 10, swedish keyboard.

Comment: It does not occur if I switch to english keyboard settings. Actually, this change appears to have resolved the problem.

Comment: Problem returned. After I do the language switch, if I compile the document, the next ^t will run the compiler again.

Comment: Going back to default settings by deleting texstudio.ini with TXS closed and then restarting TXS did not fix it.

Comment: Can you try upgrading your TXS to the latest version as well? 2.12.10. I'm not familiar with the swedish layout so not quite sure how to help. So to clarify, this problem doesn't occur with an english keyboard?

Comment: Do you have any news here?

Comment: @siracusa: The problem persists. I created a macro as a workaround. There is no need for me to hit that key combination except for transposes, so it is acceptable solution.